# JAXB marshaller throwing NullPointerException when upgrading from Java 6 to Java 7 in XMLSerializer

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jaxb2, spring-oxm

I've scoured the interwebs for a solution but I am at a loss so I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction here.

I've been tasked with upgrading an app, which makes use of JAXB2, to Java 7.

Since I understand JVM 7 can run Java 6 compiled code, that's what I tried first, and encountered a Null Pointer Exception in the com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer class.

I then recompiled the app in Java 7 and ran again and same issue.

I am using following Oracle JDK: **Java SE 7u51**
The app also uses Spring OXM which delegates to JAXB.

Here is the stack Trace of Null Pointer Exception that occurs when marshal is called on the JAXB Marshaller instance:

```
> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
> com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:627)
>   at
> com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementLeafProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementLeafProperty.java:108)
>   at
> com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:343)
>   at
> com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:685)
>   at
> com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.serializeItem(ArrayElementNodeProperty.java:54)
>   at
> com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayElementProperty.java:157)
>   at
> com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:144)
>   at
> com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:343)
>   at
> com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsSoleContent(XMLSerializer.java:582)
>   at
> com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:325)
>   at
> com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayReferenceNodeProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayReferenceNodeProperty.java:103)
>   at
> com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:144)
>   at
> com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:343)
>   at
> com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsSoleContent(XMLSerializer.java:582)
>   at
> com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:325)
>   at
> com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:483)
>   at
> com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:308)
>   at
> com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:236)
>   at
> org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.marshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:648)
```

Perhaps there is some additional configuration I am missing?

Any help appreciated.  Will provide any more info as required.

Thank you

Comment: What jars do you have in your class path or in WAR, EAR?

Comment: @mentallurg the solution jethroo posted below worked.  Looks like with Java 7 once has to add this reference impl dependency explicitly, whereas with Java 6, it was not required.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to include a reference implementation for the jaxb-impl, at least it solved the problem for [this guy with the same error](http://www.java-forum.org/xml-co/155217-probleme-xmlidref-interfaces-java-1-7-a.html)

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
   <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Looks like that did the trick!  Thanks very much!  Stack overflow never fails me :)

Comment: you are welcome, its good to have alltime backup of a nearly  infinite community ;)